# Project Euler Problem 17, Python, I Am getting wrong Answer, No Idea why

Tags: python

"Problem 17 : If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then
    there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words,
how many letters would be used?

NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens.
For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters.
The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage."

```
initDict1 = {1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine",
             11: "Eleven", 12: "Twelve", 13: "Thirteen", 14: "Fourteen", 15: "Fifteen", 16: "Sixteen", 17: "Seventeen",
             18: "Eighteen", 19: "Nineteen",
             10: "Ten", 20: "Twenty", 30: "Thirty", 40: "Forty", 50: "Fifty", 60: "Sixty", 70: "Seventy", 80: "Eighty",
             90: "Ninety", 100: "Hundred", 1000: "Thousand"}
for num in range(1, 1001):
        if num < 101:
            if num not in initDict1:
                newNum = num // 10 * 10
                initDict1[num] = initDict1[newNum] + initDict1[num % 10]
                # print(num, " : ", initDict1[newNum] + initDict1[num % 10])
        elif num < 1000:
            newNum = num // 100
            newNum1 = (newNum * 100) // newNum
            if num % 100 != 0:
                initDict1[num] = initDict1[newNum] + initDict1[newNum1] + 'And' + initDict1[num % 100]
                # print(num, " : ", initDict1[newNum] + initDict1[newNum1] +'And'+ initDict1[num % 100])
            else:
                initDict1[num] = initDict1[newNum] + 'And' + initDict1[newNum1]
                # print(num, " : ", initDict1[newNum] + 'And' +initDict1[newNum1])

wordCount = 0
for num in initDict1.values():
    wordCount += len(num)
print(wordCount)
```

The Answer I am getting is **21142** and the required answer is **21124**.

I have no Idea what I am doing wrong, I know It's going to be something stupid when answered.

Comment: Project Euler is useful not just because it gives you a reason to code through problems. It also affords you the opportunity to learn how to debug and test your own code, which is an invaluable skill. Show what research you have done, because no one really wants to debug your code for you. See this link: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What if the number is 1000? You account for <101 and <1000, but not for 1000 itself.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 That actually is not necessary as I already have 1000 in dictionary, and there is no need to re append it.

Comment: What do you put in for, e.g. "200"?

Comment: "Hundred" and "Thousand" should be "One Hundred" and "One Thousand", your other hundreds also say "<num>AndHundred" If you take your result, remove the 8 extra "And"s and add the two missing "Ones" you'll get to the right result (`21142-8*3+2*3 == 21124`)

Comment: @NickA Thanks, It worked. I knew it was something stupid. I'll remember not to reuse code without checking it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a problem in your code, if you print the results:

```
800  :  EightAndHundred
```

Answer (score 0):

The module [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) within python allows to convert the number into words. The following code works fine with me.

```
`import inflect
p = inflect.engine()


def count_digits(a, b):
    total_count = 0
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
        total_count += digit_to_word(i)
    return total_count


def digit_to_word(j):
    word = list(p.number_to_words(j))
    count = 0
    for k in word:
        if k not in [',', '-', ' ']:
            count += 1
    return count


sum1 = count_digits(1, 1000)
print(sum1)`
```